# multi level mapping in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to map over object but cannot find a way to display the the result I need. the first map is going without problems but the second maq inside the `<ul>` element is having problems.

```js
 const data = [
     {
         title: "For Clients",
         info: [
            { text: "How to hire"},

            { text: "Talent Marketplace"},
 
            { text: "Project Catalog"},
 
            { text: "Talent Scout"},
 
            { text: "Hire an Agency"},
 
            { text: "Enterprise"},
 
            { text: "Payroll Services"},
 
            { text: "Direct Contracts"},
 
            { text: "Hire Worldwide"},
 
            { text: "Hire in the USA"},
 

         ]
     },
     {
         title: "For Talent",
         info: [
            { text: "How to Find Work"},

            { text: "Direct Contracts"},
 
            { text: "Find Freelance Jobs Worldwide"},
 
            { text: "Find Freelance Jobs in the USA"},
         ]
     },
     {
         title: "Resources",
        info: [
            { text: "Help & Support"},

            { text: "Success Stories"},
 
            { text: "Upwork Reviews"},
 
            { text: "Resources"},
 
            { text: "Blog"},
 
            { text: "Community"},
 
            { text: "Affiliate Program"},
 
            { text: "Free Business tools"},
        ]
     },
     {
         title: "Company",
        info: [
            { text: "About Us"},

            { text: "Leadership"},
 
            { text: "Investor Relations"},
 
            { text: "Careers"},
 
            { text: "Our Impact"},
 
            { text: "Press"},
 
            { text: "Contact Us"},
 
            { text: "Trust, Safety & Security"},
 
            { text: "Modern Slavery Statement"},
        ]
     },

 ]
```

```html
  {data.map((item, i) => (
                    <div className="item">
                    <div className="title flex justify-between" onClick={() => toggle(i)}>
                        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                        <span>{selected === i ? "<" : ">"}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className={selected === i ? "show" : "hide"}>
                        <ul>
                            {data.map((word)=>(
                                <li>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="#">{word.info.text}</a>
                                    </p>
                                </li>
                                ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you would like to output each items info you need to change your code to this:

```
item.info.map((word)
```

and then output the text like:

```
{word.text}
```

Comment: Thank you once again. I'll push the accept button as soon as it gives me the opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

In the second map function inside the  element, you are using data.map((word) => ...) instead of item.info.map((word) => ...). This causes the error because data is an array of objects, and you need to access the info property of each object to map over it.

To fix this issue, you should change the inner map function to item.info.map((word) => ...):

```
{item.info.map((word) => (
<li>
    <p>
        <a href="#">{word.text}</a>
    </p>
</li>
))}
```

Here's the corrected code:

```
{data.map((item, i) => (
<div className="item">
    <div className="title flex justify-between" onClick={() => toggle(i)}>
        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        <span>{selected === i ? "<" : ">"}</span>
    </div>
    <div className={selected === i ? "show" : "hide"}>
        <ul>
            {item.info.map((word) => (
                <li>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#">{word.text}</a>
                    </p>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
 ))}
```

Now, the inner map function will correctly map over the info array of each object in the data array, allowing you to display the desired result.